# How to set up different documentroot for ip based requests, and different for domain based requests

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

My problem is simply that I have a domain, let's say example.com, and my server's ip address is e.g. 192.168.0.1.

I want to set up 2 different virtual hosts, so when user enters ip address (192.168.0.1) in his browser, he will see content from here: /var/www/staging

But if user will type example.com, he will see content from here: /var/www

I think it's possible but I was playing around with it and couldn't make it work.

Also I don't want to make simple redirection. I know I can, but I need both of my apps (live & staging) working in root on the same server. I can't buy second domain, and I can't associate new ip address.

Comment: Why -1? if it's impossible then let me know. If I'm missing any info - let me know as well... I will provide.

Comment: Why can't you buy another domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

With name-based virtual hosts, requests without a `Host:` header or with the `Host:` header set to an IP address will go to the default virtual host.

Requests with the `Host:` header set to `example.com` will go to the first virtual host listed that matches that name in either the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive.

You can use `apache2ctl -S` to see what virtual hosts you currently have configured and which one is the default.

Comment: I made it yesterday in exactly this way, and it works. I thought I will post my working solution today, but you were first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would be very much easier if you just used [Name Based Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). Configure your DNS with A records pointing example.com and staging.example.com to the machine's IP address and then have two vhosts suitably configured waiting to respond

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName staging.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why can't I mark two questions as accepted...